# Reverting git repository to previous commit in Android Studio

Tags: android, git, github, version-control, rollback

I am working on an Android application for a school project and need assistance.

I am new to collaborative development and version control with Github and I need to know how to revert to a previous commit using Android Studio's implementation of Git version control.

I was just about to commit a large chunk of new code and before doing so, I decided to update my project with the latest version on Github. Unfortunately, I blindly used the merge settings the IDE provided and now my project is pretty messed up.

I was hoping that someone may be able to instruct me on how to revert to a previous commit in Github.

Comment: No I did not. Is that what you are supposed to do before you update? @DilumN

Comment: Or you have to commit your changes to a new branch before get the latest version. Git pull will also ask you about the conflicts. But seems like you did something --hard here

Comment: Ok so is there something I can do at this point? If worse comes to worse I need to be able to get back to the last commit. @DilumN

Comment: Did you remember the exact command you entered to get the latest version?

Comment: I did it through the Android Studio IDE. I just clicked the blue VCS arrow in the toolbar @DilumN

Comment: @mapage2 what are the options you selected in the dialog, after you clicked the VCS arrow

Comment: Update type merge and Using Stash and just clicked ok after that @Moses

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.Remove all un-commited changes.

2.Apply the changes from the stash by selecting from the stash list.

```
Git->UnstashChanges -> (select the first one) ->ApplyStash
```

3.Commit your changes

4.Then use the VCS arrow to pull and merge the changes from the remote repository

Comment: So I am unsure if your solution is doing this but I want to go back to a previous commit If I could not get back to Index right before I updated my code

Comment: @mapage2 I'm sure it will work based on what you have mentioned above. If you want, you can take a copy of the project folder for backup

Comment: Ok so can this be done through android studio? I am unfamiliar with running the commands

Comment: yes, you can do it by android  studio. It's possible by "commands" also.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @player87

**Android Studio Instructions:** if you want to do this in Android Studio, press alt + 9 (or Command + 9 on Mac) to open the Version Control panel. Switch to the Log tab and right click on a previous commit. Select Checkout Revision.

---

**Command line instructions:** Open the command line tool you are using. Go to the Android app's Git directory (using cd). Execute git log and find the previous commit you want to revert to.

```
commit 7c247be6d8975dc88f6cc2631c154786a1f3b79e
Author: John Doe <john@doe.ca>
Date:   Fri Jun 11 22:37:35 2015 -0400

    Some helpful commit message should be here.
```

If that is the commit you want to revert to, then execute `git checkout 7c247b`.